# Add multiple executable to single gtest in Bazel

Tags: c++, testing, cmake, bazel

Colleagues,

I have 2 executable and 2 shell scripts for test. In Cmake I have:

```
add_executable(test1 test1.cpp)
add_executable(test2 test2.cpp)
add_test(NAME test_bin COMMAND test1 test2)
```

and

```
add_test(NAME test_sh
    COMMAND s1.sh e1.sh)
set_tests_properties(test_sh PROPERTIES TIMEOUT 1.1)
```

how to do the same in Bazel BUILD? I cannot use separate command line because the tests are the part of the project and I cannot change cmd arguments

Comment: I'm unclear what your question is. You just define a test target for each and a test suite (I think that was the name) target for the two tests.

Comment: I have to run both executable at the same time (two processes) in single test. Then I need to run both shell scripts and set timeout property
P.S. there is timeout argument in sh_test and cc_test functions in bazel, but for changing timeout value it is need to use --test_timeout command line argument. But if I have 12 tests with different timeout values I cannot do that

Comment: I'm not that deep into Bazel to say it doesn't have something built-in, but I'd expect this to be too special of a case. So, write a program (Python or shell script) that sets up the two executables and then runs the two shell scripts.

Comment: Wrapper for both tests? good point. BTW, I checked bazel docs about timeouts and yes, bazel has only 4 steps of timeout. Start point can be changed from command line.